# Trouble pre-selecting value coming from database in HTML select

Tags: jquery

I've got partially working code to select the correct value coming from MySql/PHP in a drop down.

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function ( $ ) {
  $( '#hosp_country' ).find( 'option[value=<?php echo $tE['hosp_country']; ?>]' ).attr( 'selected', 'selected' );
   } );
```

If the value - $tE['hosp_country'] - is a single word, everything works properly and the correct value is selected in the select - "Argentina" or "Armenia", for example.

If the value is more than one word with a space, the value isn't selected. "Bovet Island" or "Czech Republic", for example.

What do I have incorrect?

Comment: try enclosing your value with double quotes.
option[value="<?php echo $tE['hosp_country']; ?>"]

Comment: Amazing what a second set of eyes can spot so quickly.
Thank you very much! I should have seen that!!!

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is that you're not enclosing your value attribute's value with double quotes inside your jquery attribute selector.

Correct code is below:

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function ( $ ) {
  $( '#hosp_country' ).find( 'option[value="<?php echo $tE['hosp_country']; ?>"]' ).attr( 'selected', 'selected' );
});
```

But there's a better way of doing what you want. just give the value you want to the select input, and that's all.

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  // Give the value to select input
  $('#hosp_country').val('Czech Republic');
  // With php, your code should look like:
  // $('#hosp_country').val('<?php echo $tE['hosp_country']; ?>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="hosp_country">
  <option>Argentina</option>
  <option>Armenia</option>
  <option>Czech Republic</option>
  <option>Bovet Island</option>
</select>
```